# Wordpress ajax form submission without using wordpress functions possible?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently making a site on Wordpress and need a form to be submitted via ajax is it possible to do this without using Wordpress functions? My current code has no errors and returns a success message without updating the database. I don't understand why it's not working please have a look at my simplified version -

**This is the form HTML -**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="formAppointment" name="appointmentform">
    <input type="text" name="message_first_name" value="" placeholder="First name" id="appointmentFirstName">
    <input type="text" name="message_last_name" value="" placeholder="Last name" id="appointmentLastName">
    <input type="tel" name="message_phone" value="" placeholder="Phone" id="appointmentPhone">
    <input type="submit" id='appointmentSubmit' class='xAnim' name="submit">
</form>
```

**This is the jquery AJAX -**

```
$("#formAppointment").submit(function(e){
    var firstname    = $("#appointmentFirstName").val();
    var lastname     = $('#appointmentLastName').val();
    var phone        = $('#appointmentPhone').val();
    var dataString = 'message_first_name='+ firstname + '&message_last_name=' + lastname + '&message_phone=' + phone;


    if(firstname.trim() == "" || lastname.trim() == "" || phone.trim() == ""){

        alert('missing information');

         e.preventDefault();  

    } else { 

        // AJAX Code To submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            console.log(dataString);
            alert('success');

            }
        });
    }
    return false;

});
```

**This is the php located in process.php**

```
include "config.php";

$patientfirstname                = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message_first_name']);
$patientlastname                 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message_last_name']);
$patientcontactnumber            = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message_phone']);

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO data_table (firstname, lastname, phonenumber ) VALUES ('$patientfirstname', '$patientlastname', '$patientcontactnumber')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: you have to do `preventDefault()` when doing an ajax request on submit, to prevent the form submit/page reload

Comment: The page is already not reloading and the success message is being displayed but form data is not being submitted

Comment: have you checked the data you are sending is, you getting or not. i mean just return the data you are sending on the ajax request  first for the checking you get the data in the response or not after that if you are getting the data in the response that means ajax request is right and problem is with your  database query not with ajax request.

Comment: please try $_GET['message_first_name'] as well at the place of post $_POST['message_first_name'] may be it will work because one time i also getting the same problem.

Comment: hmm thanks yea just tried that didn't work

Comment: Note that your PHP code as it is now is open to [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You'll want to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass data as object, not as dataString.

```
$("#formAppointment").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstname = $("#appointmentFirstName").val();
    var lastname = $('#appointmentLastName').val();
    var phone = $('#appointmentPhone').val();
    // var dataString = 'message_first_name=' + firstname + '&message_last_name=' + lastname + '&message_phone=' + phone;
    var data = {
        "message_first_name": firstname,
        "message_last_name": lastname,
        "message_phone": phone,
    }   

    if (firstname.trim() == "" || lastname.trim() == "" || phone.trim() == "") {    
        alert('missing information');     
    } else {    
        // AJAX Code To submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                alert('success');    
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**NOTE**: You are missing `email` and `message` in the code. So the line `if(firstname.trim() == "" || lastname.trim() == "" || email.trim() == "" || message.trim() == "")` may raise some errors and js skips the execution of remaining code

Comment: thanks i updated my post but this still doesn't seem to work, do you think because it's on Wordpress I need to use the Wordpress ajax functions?

Comment: Can you check the console for any kind of errors.And also go through the network tab for analysing request and response

Comment: No errors in console and nothing out of the ordinary within the network tab

Comment: I assume it is? as the success alert is being displayed on submit? is there another way I can check this?

Comment: You are telling that the ajax call is made successfully and success response is received. The only problem is data not saving..right?

Comment: correct - on submit success message is displayed but when i check database no new record is created

Comment: on the network tab check the response. Or you can simply go through the console window. because, on success the result is printing on the console

Comment: I just checked in network and on submit it's returning a status 200 ok on process.php with the correct form data but still no update to the database

Comment: Check the response from the server. make sure its "New record created successfully".. If not please provide the message

Comment: oh no i don't get that i just get the alert that says "success". I also get some warnings that were existent before i tried to implement ajax into my form but i don't think they should matter? there are -

Comment: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wpse_load_plugin_css' not found or invalid function name in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Comment: please correct the php script. That may raising the issue. The status code you are returning for both success and error operation is 200. Thats why ajax success block is getting executed

Comment: ok I updated my php script and it now updates the database with a new row but it doesn't pick up the form data for some reason I'm guessing there is something wrong with the ajax call? I updated my question with the new php can you please have a look? i'll be tinkering around

Comment: What you mean by that. Did you replaced the `dataString` with the `data`

Comment: yes changed to datastring to data and changed php script from pdo to mysqli and it works now

Comment: k. nice. If it solved your issue please mark it as answer and give an upvote